# Programmaticaly parse journalctl to initiate an action

Tags: logging, cron, systemd-journald

When my 3d printer runs out of filament, it pauses without sending any alert message. The only entry I can find is a message that on journalctl like this one:
`Jan 22 04:36:39 ultimakersystem-flipflop_wsgi.py[2884]: INF - root:80 - PrintJobStatus updated! 6e408dcf-9887, paused`

I absolutely need to be alerted when the printer pauses, or else the print will be ruined. Is there a way to poll/parse journalctl programmatically, e.g. via a bash or python script, and send an email as appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are likely other ways to do this more *elegantly* than polling, but FWIW:

1. `journalctl` can time-filter its output; e.g. to see the last 30 minutes activity:

```sh
journalctl --since "30 min ago" --until "now"
```

2. `cron` can run jobs at various intervals; e.g. to run the above `journalctl` job every 30 minutes, put this line in your `crontab`:

```
0,30 * * * * /bin/journalctl --since "30 min ago" --until "now"
```

3. The `journalctl` output above must be checked for a match with the ***log entry of interest***. From the error message you posted, I don't know exactly what *key words* tip off an empty filament bin, but let's assume for now that they are `ultimakersystem` and `paused`. `awk` provides an extensible way to find matching words & phrases: `awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/'` matches when both patterns occur in the same line of `journalctl` output, so add a `pipe` from the `journalctl` output to `awk`; the `cron` job above is modified as follows:

```
0,30 * * * * /bin/journalctl --since "30 min ago" --until "now" | awk '/ultimakersystem/ && /paused/'
```

4. The final step is to test if `awk` found a match, and if so, send a message to the designated user. In the event of one or more matches, only one email need be sent, and so the match test will be performed in an `END` section. The `cron` job is updated again as follows:

```
0,30 * * * * /bin/journalctl --since "30 min ago" --until "now" | awk '/ultimakersystem/ && /paused/ {m=1}; END { if (m == 1){system("cat warn.txt | mail -s FILAMENT_NEEDED $USER")} }'
```

`awk` uses a *pattern-action* paradigm; `/ultimakersystem/ && /paused/` is the *pattern*, and `{m=1}` is the *action*. After `awk` has processed all the `journalctl` output, the `END` section is executed. A simple `if (m == 1)` test determines if one or more matches occurred, and if so, the `mail` command is invoked to send the message defined in `warn.txt`. GNU `awk`'s `system` function [REF](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#I_002fO-Functions) provides access to the system's repertoire of commands.

Among many other possibilities for changing this recipe, a *date-time stamp* can be inserted into the body of the email by replacing `cat warn.txt` with `date`, and sending mail to a someone other than `$USER`. See `man mail`, or your email client's documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue with a python script. I think that it's more efficient that a cronjob because it will react whenever it finds the keyword (in this case the word "pause"), without a need to poll.

```
import systemd.journal
import socket
from time import sleep
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTP

def main():
  j = systemd.journal.Reader()
  j.seek_tail()
  j.get_previous()
  while True:
    event = j.wait(-1)
    if event == systemd.journal.APPEND:
      for entry in j:
         print (entry['MESSAGE'])
         alertmail(entry['MESSAGE'])

def alertmail(logEntry):
    # returns first occurrence of Substring
    trigger_text = 'pause'
    result = logEntry.find(trigger_text)
    if (logEntry.find(trigger_text) != -1):
        print ("Contains '" + trigger_text + "' at index:", result)

        fromaddr = "ultimaker@mymailstrasse.com"
        toaddrs  = "aag@bluewin.ch"
        msg = "ultimaker has paused!!! " + logEntry
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP('mail.mymailstrasse.com', port='587')
        smtp.ehlo()  # send the extended hello to our server
        smtp.starttls()  # tell server we want to communicate with TLS encryption
        smtp.login('ultimaker@mail.mymailstrasse.com', 'pw')  # login to our email server

        # send our email message 'msg' to our boss
        smtp.sendmail('ultimaker@mail.mymailstrasse.com',
                    'aag@bluewin.ch',
                    msg)
                    
        smtp.quit()  # finally, don't forget to close the connection
    else:
        print ("Doesn't contain given substring")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Good show !  I'm no good w/ Python, so I wonder if you could answer a question: I gather the code is prompted to inspect each new log entry from the APPEND event. Do you know *how* that event is generated? I wonder if this is done in a systemd unit?

Comment: And BTW: You should *license* this to the *ultimaker* manufacturer. It seems negligent of them not to have an in-built alert system given the impact. Even my Capressa bean-to-cup coffee machine won't try to brew a cup if there are no beans in the hopper!  LOL

Comment: yes, I buggered them for 3 years that they MUST build some kind of push message whenever the printer encounters some trouble. They ignored me, so I took things in my own hands...